# How to prevent scrubbing from ending the presentation with Media Foundation

Tags: windows, winapi, ms-media-foundation

I'm currently implementing scrubbing using Media Foundation. It works nicely so far but there's one problem: When seeking to near the end of the stream, Media Foundation automatically triggers `MEEndOfPresentation` instead of `MESessionScrubSampleComplete`. Note that I'm **not** seeking beyond the stream end, just to near the stream end. The duration of my video stream is 3173933333 hns and I'm seeking to 3173920000 hns so the seek target is still within the boundaries of the stream and I don't see why this should trigger a `MEEndOfPresentation` event. Still, whenever I seek to near the end Media Foundation immediately triggers `MEEndOfPresentation` and there is no `MESessionScrubSampleComplete` at all.

The code is like this:

```
PROPVARIANT var;

// enable scrubbing
pRateControl->SetRate(FALSE, 0.0f);

PropVariantInit(&var);

var.vt = VT_I8;
var.hVal.QuadPart = 3173920000;
       
pSession->Start(GUID_NULL, &var);
PropVariantClear(&var);
```

As I said, the code works fine *except* this single case when seeking to near the end of the stream.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you get the `IMFRateControl` interface from the Media Session as the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/medfound/how-to-perform-scrubbing#to-perform-scrubbing)? And could you please share a [minimal,complete and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?